# Using Matlab's filter() function for solving difference equation with initial conditions

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I am trying to solve a difference equation with initial conditions using Matlab's `filter` function:

$$y[n]=\frac12y[n-1]+x[n],\qquad y[-1]=1\tag{1}$$

For $x[n]=6u[n]$, calculation of $y[n]$ by hand gives

$$y[n]=\left[12-(6-y[-1]/2)\left(\frac12\right)^n\right]u[n]\tag{2}$$

However, the solution produced by `filter` is different. Could anybody point out my mistake?

The code is shown below:

```
disp('Solution of a difference equation:')
% The example difference equation considered is
% y(n) = 0.5y(n-1) + x(n) 
num_coef = [ 1 ]; % coefficient of x
den_coef = [1 -0.5]; % coefficient of y
n = 0:4; % Considering five samples 
x = 6 * ones(1,5) % x(n) = 6u(n)
init_cond = [1];  % y(-1) = 1
y = filter(num_coef, den_coef, x, init_cond) % Solution returned by 'filter'
yM = 12 - (11/2)*(1/2).^n % Solution obtained manually
plot(y);hold on; % PLots for comparison
plot(yM,'r')
```

Comment: Hi! So, how are the solutions different? What *are* these solutions? What **is** your manual calculation? With the info you're giving, it's hard to even guess, impossible to answer with confidence.

Comment: Is your "manually obtained solution" a step response or an impulse response? Your test signal is a constant sequence of length 5, which will give you neither. If you want so see an impulse response, input a signal like [1,0,0,...]. If you want to see the step response, input a *long* sequence of ones.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I agree that it would have been nicer to give a Latex formula for the manual solution, but note that the solution is given as `yM` in the code, so all information is there, just not in a greatly reader-friendly form. I think that despite all its weaknesses the question shouldn't be closed because it shows an important aspect of the commonly used Matlab function `filter`, namely that it's not correct to supply $y[-1]$ etc. as initial states.

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: oh, thanks, @MattL.

Comment: Thank you all for organizing the question and answering it too... The filtic function is useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the definition of the initial condition of the function `filter()`. Note that according to the [mathworks reference page](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html), `filter` is implemented using a direct-form II transposed structure. If you look at the corresponding [diagram](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buaif7c-5), you see that the filter states (called $w_k(m)$ in the figure) are defined *after* multiplication with the respective filter coefficients.

So in your example if you want to initialize `filter` with some past output value $y[-1]$, your initial state is given by $y[-1]\cdot 0.5$ because that's the value of the input of the delay element.

`y = filter(num_coef, den_coef, x, 0.5)`

should give you the expected result.

Note that for the general case there's the function [filtic](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtic.html), which computes the necessary initial conditions given past output samples (and, if necessary, past input samples). For your example you would use the command

`zi = filtic(num_coef, den_coef, 1)`

which results in `zi = 0.5`, as explained above.